# php7.2-fpm.sock is Corrupted

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm using PHP-FPM for my Nginx.  It was working fine in the beginning, not sure what I did but the file, **php7.2-fpm.sock=** has **zero** bites.  When I stop `php7.2-fpm.service`, the processes are gone but I start it back up, `php7.2-fpm.service` still has zero bytes. I tried to uninstall PHP-FPM, and purging it, and reinstall it but the outcome is still the same.

```
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   **0** Jun 29 17:56 **php7.2-fpm.sock=**
```

Has anyone ever encounter this problem before, where the `php7.2-fpm.sock=` is zero bytes in size??

Comment: Did you do `killall -9 php7.2-fpm`, then purge the install for it completely, then reinstall it?

Comment: The file is a socket, a way to pass information between two processes. So you will always see it as 0 bytes, but this has no impact to its operations. What bothers you with this file being 0 bytes? Whatever your problem is (and it is not clear what it is), it is certainly not related to this file being 0 bytes.

Comment: My script just read a simple PHP file and display the output.  Here’s my code:

`user www-data;
events {}
http { 
  include mime.types;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.0.20;
    root /data/sites/demo;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @ Patrick Mevzek

This is PHP script:
`<h1>Date: <?php echo date("l jS F"); ?></h1>`

I’m running:
OS: Ubuntu 8.3.0-6
Web App: nginx/1.17.0

It must be the php7.1-fpm.sock that’s causing me grief.

Answer (score 2):

I've upgraded the php-fpm version from 7.1 to 7.2 but I forgot to update my nginx.conf file.

Change From:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```

To:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

I feel so stupid right now.